# Is there any other way to get vscode running?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tried reinstalling vscode from Microsoft Store as well , tried running it as administrator as well , tried running it in compatibility mode win xp yet it shows no signs to open . Can you guys help me with this issue . Thanking you in advance!!!

I tried running reinstalling it for 3 times yet it ain't running....

Comment: If I guessed it right! you are trying to run Visual studio code from windows xp ? if so, which visual studio code version did you install?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run Visual Studio Code on Windows XP OS please try to install an **older version**.

I would suggest **Visual Studio Code 2017 (version 1.14)**

- You can download it from here:

  https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14